# Closure of a finite cover of sets

Tags: general-topology

Suppose I had a compact set $X$ which can be disconnected into two closed in $X$ , nonempty, disjoint sets $A$ and $B$.  Then $A$ would have an open cover of neighborhoods centered at points $a \in A$.  That is, $A \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{N}N_X(a_i,\epsilon_i):=U$.  We extract a similar finite cover for $B\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{M}N_X(b_i,\epsilon_i):=V$.

Is there a way I can guarantee that $U \cap V=\emptyset$?

Comment: You can take the neighborhoods of the elements in $A$ as subsets of $A$ since $A$ is open as complement of closed $B$. The same is true for the neighborhoods in $B$. Then $U=A$ and $V=B$ so the sets are disjoint. This works in *space* $X$, but you are talking about a compact *set* $X$. Is $X$ a subset of some larger space $Y$ here?

Comment: $X$ is just a compact subset of $R^2$.  There was just a remark on the board as follows: $A \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{N}N_X(a_i,\epsilon_i)\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{N}Cl(N_X(a_i,\epsilon_i))\subseteq X\setminus B$.  I was confused how that came about.  But he remarked that this would allow us to know that $U \cap V=\emptyset$.

Comment: you can start with neighborhoods of elements of $A$ such that the closure of each does not meet $B$, Then there is a finite union $U$ that covers compact $A$ and the union of the closures is a closed set that does not meet $B$. Now   the open complement (call it $V$) of this union is a neighborhood for all elements in $B$ and does not meet $U$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (see comment of OP) is compact, hence closed ($\mathbb{R}^{2}$
is Hausdorff).

Then the sets $A,B$ - closed in $X$ - are compact
and closed.

Open $B^{c}$ contains $A$ so for every $a\in A$ there
is some $\epsilon_{a}>0$ with $N\left(a,\epsilon_{a}\right)\cap B=\emptyset$.

Here $x\in N\left(a,\epsilon_{a}\right)\iff\left\Vert x-a\right\Vert <\epsilon_{a}$
and $x\in\overline{N\left(a,\epsilon_{a}\right)}\iff\left\Vert x-a\right\Vert \leq\epsilon_{a}$
so choosing $\epsilon$ small enough we have $\overline{N\left(a,\epsilon_{a}\right)}\cap B=\emptyset$.

Since $A$ is compact we can find $a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}\in A$ such
that $A$ is covered by $U:=\cup_{i=1}^{n}N\left(a_{i},\epsilon_{a_{i}}\right)$.
Note that $\overline{U}=\cup_{i=1}^{n}\overline{N\left(a_{i},\epsilon_{a_{i}}\right)}$
so that $\overline{U}\cap B=\emptyset$.

For every $b\in B$ some $\epsilon_{b}>0$
exists with $\overline{U}\cap N\left(b,\epsilon_{b}\right)=\emptyset$.

$B$ is compact so we can find $b_{1},\ldots,b_{m}\in B$ such that
$B$ is covered by $V:=\cup_{i=1}^{m}N\left(b_{i},\epsilon_{b_{i}}\right)$.

Here $U\cap V\subset \overline{U}\cap V=\emptyset$ .